# How can i send a MultipartFormDataContent array to an api using c#

Tags: c#

I want to send a multipartformDataContent array to an api.

```
MultipartFormDataContent[] content = new MultipartFormDataContent[Array.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
            {
                foreach (var para in Array[i])
                {
                    if (para.Key == "file")
                    {
                        FileParameter fileToUpload = (FileParameter)para.Value;
                        var stream = new MemoryStream(fileToUpload.File);
                        content[i].Add(new StreamContent(stream), para.Key, fileToUpload.FileName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String String = para.Value.ToString();
                        content[i].Add(new StringContent(String), para.Key);
                    }
                }

            }
```

I want to post this multipartformdataContent array to an api. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you have an array? To achieve MultiMultipart?

Comment: We are implementing a batch mail send(multiple mail send).So input will be an array of json object .Each object have their own tomail, from mail datas and a file attachment.So I am trying it with a multipartformdatacontent array

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's needed to combine FileContent with other data into MultipartFormDataContent:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Copy your file into memoryStream
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
    var multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent {{fileContent, "File", "Blah.pdf"}};
    foreach (var pair in nameValues)
    {
        multiContent.Add(new StringContent(pair.Value), pair.Key);
    }

    return await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, multiContent);
}
```